# Linux: How to merge identical named folders with different case from the CLI (BASH preferred)

Tags: bash, merge, shared-folders, case-sensitivity

I have on my Linux NAS miscellaneous folders with identical names, except for case,like this:

- /data/libraries
- /Data/libraries/presets
- /Data/Libraries/presets
- /Data/Libraries/Presets
- /merged/readme
- /merged/Readme
- /merged/ReadMe
- /merged/README
- etc.

This is ok-ish on Linux, even though not desirable, but because this is on a NAS that services Windows PCs, the client PCs get confused and only actually show the content of one of the folders, despite showing all the variations...

There are so many, that I want to automate merging these folders together.

What capitalization we end up with is really irrelevant, although a format of 'Capitalized First Letter Of Each Word' would be preferred, if remotely possible, the ultimate goal is to just have one of each folder name.

(NOTE: I am aware that there may be conflicts in the file names contained in these folders as well, but after discussing, I'm willing to take the risk that there might be identically named files with different content, simply because currently a lot of the content isn't even readily accessible anyway!)

Are there any ready-made CLI tools (or BASH scripts) to do this?

Comment: Are these meant to be the same case-insensitive file/folder names?  in that case, you should use a case-insensitive filesystem.   What kind of NAS is it?  a DIY NAS running Linux? If so, you can use ext4 with the case-insensitivity feature (requires kernel 5.2 or later), or ZFS (I run my steam folders on zfs datasets with `casesensitivity=insensitive` to avoid problems caused by lazy windows developers who don't use consistent capitalisation for file/dir names.....and symlinks for the dumb ones that make both "Electronic Arts" and mis-spelled "Electron**t**ic Arts" folders).

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with ext4's case-insensitivity but AFAIK, if you're using ext4, enabling it will require a backup, reformat with `mkfs -t ext4 -O casefold ...`, and restore.  Then you can selectively enable case-insensitivity on directories with `chattr +F`.

Comment: As for merging the directories, pick one and just move the files in the others into it.  Resolving any conflicts will probably be difficult and require individual examination of each file to decide which one to keep.   You could check the sizes or use something like `md5sum` to compare the files.  I'd recommend NOT just overwriting any conflicting files but renaming them to .bak or .1, .2, .3, etc.  Turn the other directories into symlinks (or, better yet, convert the fs to enable case-insensitivity).

Comment: Thanks for the comments...

I'ts self built and I am using ZFS, and in hindsight a case insensitive FS would have been nice. 

I could create a separate dataset for the NAS Share 'folder' with case insensitivity. I assume that when I copy the data to the new dataset, the additional folders would get compacted in to the first instance that was written, ie based on the above list, '/Data/Libraries/Presets' would get merged in to '/Data/libraries/presets'?

Comment: I'll have to investigate whether ZFS without case-sensitivity does still preserve case where possible, but this might just be a good option.  
  
I've ran `find . -type d | sort -f | uniq -Di | wc -l`, and the answer is 1208...  
A little too much to do manually, esp. on a headless CLI only system.

Comment: If I were to use `rsync --remove-source-files` to migrate all data from the case-sensitive dataset to the case-insensitive dataset (as `mv` probably won't work due to it not working for non-empty folders), should that do the trick?

Comment: Anyway, thanks again @cas, you've given me some ideas to work off of...

Comment: I believe it should just merge them if the destination dataset is case-insensitive, but i'd test it `--dry-run` and several `--verbose` options.   I wouldn't recommend --remove-source-files unless you're really short on space.  You can always delete it later, but it's difficult to undelete stuff that's already gone (unless you have a recent snapshot or backup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up creating a separate case-insensitive dataset for the most important subfolder (after renaming the original subfolder) and then ran rsync to move the data in to that new dataset...

Everything is now nicely consolidated, and I'm pretty happy with the end result. AFAICT we didn't lose any relevant data...  ;)
(Before starting I ran `find . | sort -f | uniq -Di`, and I only saw folders, no files, so I doubt we could have lost anything!)

There are recommendations out there to NOT do this for a Samba share because Samba is case-aware, bla bla bla, but the worst issue they can cite is that you cannot rename a file from 'Readme.txt' to 'ReadMe,txt', because the underlying ZFS will report that that file already exists... The workaround is obvious: give it a name that is different like "Read Me.txt", or temporarily rename it 'readme1.txt' before renaming it as you want...
What none of those that recommend NOT using case-insensitive FS underneath have an answer for is exactly the issue I was running in to!